# Calling a Callback after an event has been fired

Tags: javascript, events, asynccallback

I have recently been working on a project with both a client (in the browser) and node.js. I am using web sockets to communicate between the two. I have implemented an API on my server that communicates over the WebSockets and the server works just fine. In the browser, I am implementing the following class (in javascript) to interface with the API.

```
class ApiHandlerV1 {
    constructor(apiUrl) {
        //create the object
        this.ws = null;
    }

    makeRequest(request,callback) {
        //make a request
    }

    connect() {
        //connect the websocket
        this.ws = new WebSocket(this.url);
        this.ws.onmessage = function () {
            //call callback?
        }
    }
}
```

The issue that I am caught up on is that I want to be able to call makeRequest, provide a callback, and once the socket has gotten data back trigger the callback. I have thought about just re-defining `.onmessage` every time that I make a request but that just seems dirty to me and there is most likely a nice and easy solution to this.

Clarifications: Because of how I implemented my server I will only get a single message back from the server.

As Dominik pointed out in the comments I should also say that I am going to call `.connect()` before I make a request. I will be calling makeRequest multiple times after in other parts of my code.

Comment: When are you calling `connect()`? Probably not inside `makeRequest()`?

Comment: I am calling connect() first, then latter makeRequest() whenever I need to make a request.

Comment: Got ya, that now makes sense. You should add that to the question :)

Comment: Why not define your callback inside the `connect` call? Will the callback always be different? Or always the same for each request? You can store your callback in your constructor and call it later or if they are different each time implement a queue and stacks...

Comment: I want to be able to use this for many different things, for ex. authentication, messages, etc. This way my code can be as easy to maintain as making something like making HTTP requests.

Comment: [This link might help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)